# Appending a suffix using sed: why is a variable ignored in its second usage?

Tags: sed

I thought the following:

```
xx=abc ; echo "abcde-123" | sed -e s/$xx/$xx_nnn/g
```

would result in   `abcde_nnn123` .  However the result is

> de-123

As can be seen the prefix `xx=abc` is removed and the `_nnn` in the substitution
pattern is completely ignored.  Why is that happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is here: `/$xx_nnn/`
You are really passing a variable called `$xx_nnn` which actually doesn't exist.
So basically you are running:

```bash
xx=abc ; echo "abcde-123" | sed -e s/$xx//g
#or what is equivalent:
echo "abcde-123" | sed -e s/abc//g
```

And for that reason you get: `de-123`, you are replacing `abc` with nothing.

The best solution to this is to use: `${varname}`, e.g:

```bash
xx=abc ; echo "abcde-123" | sed -e "s/$xx/${xx}_nnn/g"
```

All after the `}` will not be part of the variable name.

About:

> would result in abcde_nnn123

That's will not be the result. With the `sed` command you provided you will get this:

```
abc_nnnde-123
```

So if you really want to get: `abcde_nnn123` then your code should look like this:

```bash
xx=abcde ; echo "abcde123" | sed -e "s/$xx/${xx}_nnn/g"
```

You can also replace strings using [bash parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).For example:

```bash
str='abcde123'
xx='abcde'
echo "${str/$xx/${xx}_nnn}" # means: in 'abcde123' replace 'abcde' 
#with `abcde_nnn`
```